# Is there a secure p2p distributed database?

Tags: hashtable, distributed, p2p, bittorrent

I'm looking for a distributed hash table to store and retrieve values securely. These are my requirements:

- It must use an existing popular p2p network (I must guarantee my key/value will be stored and kept in multiple peers).
- None but myself should be able to edit or delete the key/value. Ideally an encryption key that only I have access to would be required to edit my key value.
- All peers would be able to read the key value (read-only access, only the key holder would be able to edit the value)

Is there such p2p distributed hash table? 
Would the bittorrent distributed hash table meet my requirements?'

Where could I find documentation?

Comment: Documentation: https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0044.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need encryption, you need signatures.

The mainline bittorrent DHT does not allow arbitrary key value storage at the moment, only key -> IP:Port storage where the IP is fixed to the originator of the storage request. The vuze DHT on the other hand does support binary blob storage, on top of which you could implement some signature scheme.

Update: [BEP44](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0044.html) added signed or hash-based key-value storage to the bittorrent DHT. But it imposes some restrictions what can be used as keys to randomly distribute data throughout the keyspace.